# How to bind multiple custom domains and redirect to azure web app

Tags: azure

I'm going to deploy my web app which hosted in IIS (Window VM) to Azure app service as the following current behavior:

Note: mhksite.com is primary domain

```
"*:80:mhksite.com" => redirect to home page
":80:www.mhksite.com" => redirect to home page
"*:443:mhksite.com" => redirect to home page
":443:www.mhksite.com" => redirect to home page

"*:80:mhksite.reviews" => redirect to home page
"*:80:mhkwebsite.reviews" => redirect to home page

"*:80:exampleA.com" => redirect to mhksite.com/categories/subcategory
"*:80:otherdomaim.com => redirect to mhksite.com/products/otherproduct
"*:80:www.exampleA.com" => redirect to mhksite.com/categories/subcategory
```

Could I do all these requirements in Azure App Service? or other part will be completed in domain provider?

Thanks

Comment: I've used a proxy called Cloudflare to achieve something like this.

Answer (score 4):

You can add as many domain bindings as you want on your Azure App Service (http + https).

But this is just a binding between the domain name and the application.

You can use Sitecore site config to map these domains to different sites in Sitecore.

Forwards and redirects to other url's like *mhksite.com/categories/subcategory* will have to be done either in the code of your web application.

Another option for the forwards or redirects is to do them before you arrive on the App Service by using **Azure Frontdoor Service** or just configure them on your **Domain Provider**.

Comment: +1 just configure them on your Domain Provider

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above answer you can add multiple domains as you need.

Apart from that, you will need below.

1. you need to have URL Rewrite module in-app service.
2. you need to add RedirectRule.config file with all redirect rules you need.
3. At the app service level, you can use the [Azure Traffic Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/) for domain-level redirection.
4. you can also use redirect rule at DNS level from Domain provider.
5. you can also introduce [redshield](https://www.redshield.co/) in front of your DNS where all redirections can be managed.